# Go to next SQL row from current row by pressing previous and next buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a site that has a database of videos that I need to go through by pressing back and previous buttons. Each video is a row in the database and has a link, image, and title that I need to pull.

Currently, I have thumbnails of the videos and can swap the attributes of the main video using PHP and jQuery like this:

```
<?php foreach( $allData as $data ) {
    echo '<div class="bit-3">';
    echo '<a class="video-link" href=' . "{$data->vid_link}" . '?&autoplay=1&a=1' . '>';
    echo '<img src="' . "{$data->vid_thumb}" . '"/>';
    echo "<h3>{$data->vid_title}</h3>";
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>

$('.video-link').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var changeVid = $(this).attr('href'),
        changeBg = $(this).children().attr('src'),
        changeTitle = $(this).find('h3').text();

    $('#bg').attr('src', changeBg);
    $('#video').attr('src', changeVid);
    $('h1').text(changeTitle);

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 100);

});
```

This works pretty well to click on a thumbnail and then play a specific video.

What I need to do is play a video at the top of the screen and then go to the next video when I click the next button. I was thinking ajax would be useful for this but I can't figure out how have a "current video" and then increment something to go back and forward through PHP.

This is my SQL request now that gets everything:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM berm_videos');
```

Here is a link to the current website: [live website](http://dsrp.tv/derp)

EDIT: I've made some progress. I've formatted the query like this:

```
function get_videos( $number ) {
    global $pdo; 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
            SELECT * 
            FROM  `berm_videos` 
            WHERE  `ID` = :number 
        ');
         $stmt->execute( array( ':number' => $number . '%') );

         return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
}
```

and then pass in a value like this:

```
$allData = get_videos( 1 );
```

If I could just figure out a way to POST if the previous or next button has been clicked I think I would be able to increment that number and then pass it to a new query?

Although, as I work on this. It does seem really inefficient to keep making these queries for every click...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm47898269683008

Comment: I see how to get 1 row back but I don't see how to increment that or get to the next or previous one. Is there a way to pull all rows and then increment them outside of the query?

Comment: Are you looking for pagination?

Comment: No, I want to avoid pagination. I want to cycle through videos by clicking previous and next buttons using ajax (as far as I understand). The videos are in a MYSQL database and I'm using PHP to access them.

Comment: You can easily achieve that by doing a pagination and limiting 1 to each page. You could use ajax pagination with next and previous without having numbered links.

Comment: Can you please point me to a tutorial or help me with the basics? I am really struggling with this.

Comment: I've gotten as far as showing JSON here: [link](http://dsrp.tv/derp/ajax.php?page=1&items_per_page=1) I don't know how to take this further.

Comment: @EmptyPockets There are many around on the web, just search for 'ajax pagination', you'll have to edit it so that the numbers dont show.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up working all night on it and got at least the concept of it working. I had a lot of starts and stops. Right now the last thing I need to figure out is how to setup previous and next buttons instead of direct pagination. I'm not sure how to increment in PHP but trigger it in javascript.